# MVC/MVP and scalability

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, mvp

I've been working on a project while implementing the MVP design-pattern (at least to my knowledge) where i just have my one controller/presenter class which handles all of the actions from UI point of view using inner classes

```
public class PresenterClass {
    public PresenterClass(ViewClass view) {
        view.getButtonComponent().addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        view.getMenuItem().addActionListener(new MenuItemListener());
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Do some action with the button
        }
    }

    class MenuItemListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Do some action with the menu item
        }
    }

}
```

Worth it to know that each new class listener is created for any new component that needs it and it isn't just a generic listener for all Buttons, so you can end up with a lot of inner classes which is what is happening in my project. My project isn't massive but it's growing and while i don't think it would be big enough to be completely unmanageable i have thought about how i could handle it if i needed to handle hundreds of different components? So this leads to the question of:

How do you handle large scalability while implementing an MVC or MVP design pattern?

Comment: Just as a terminology note, scalability generally refers to the ability of an application to handle increasing amounts of work (generally in the form of high numbers of users), not the manageability of the code base.

Comment: @Aurand Okay, but i feel that the idea of the question is still understandable. If anyone wants to edit the question to include the correct terminology while still getting across the message of the question is free to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write reusable business logic in MVC models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892396/how-to-write-reusable-business-logic-in-mvc-models)